# Compute array intersection, preserve header order?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
<?php
$row = array(
  'useless' => 42,
  'useful' => 'orange',
  'useful_also' => 'apples',
  'useless_too' => 'banana',
  'useful_too' => 'apples');
$header = array('useful_too', 'useful', 'useful_also');
```

How can I get the following array?

```
   <?php
   $result = array(
      'useful_too' => 'apples',
      'useful'     => 'orange',
      'useful_also' => 'apples'
   );
```

I was using `array_intersect_key`, but it would not use the second
array order, but the first. I guess I'll use a simple foreach for the
moment, like this:

```
<?php
$result = array();
foreach ($header as $key) {
    $result[$key] = $row[$key];
}
```

but I was wondering if there was a solution without a foreach.

Comment: Usually the order of entries in associative arrays is not significant. Why do you care?

Comment: Maybe this contains an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438098/php-sorting-array-intersect-key-results-by-second-array

Comment: @Barmar : Because I'm going to use this as an argument for SplFileObject::fputcsv

Comment: @MatthiasDunkel : Oh yeah, `array_replace` looks like it could do the job. Why don't you write an answer ?

Comment: How is `foreach` less "elegant" than a hard to read tangle of `array_*` functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$row = array(
      'useless' => 42,
      'useful' => 'orange',
      'useful_also' => 'apples',
      'useless_too' => 'banana',
      'useful_too' => 'apples');
$header = array('useful_too', 'useful', 'useful_also');

$list  = array_flip($header);
$arr   = array_intersect_key(array_replace($list, $row), $list);
print_r($arr);
```

See **[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vBPX6r)**

Comment: Why reverse it? He wants the specific order from `$header`, not just the reverse of the order from `$row`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question over here: [PHP sorting array_intersect_key() results by second array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438098/php-sorting-array-intersect-key-results-by-second-array)

It looks like `array_replace()` could do the job.

Comment: If you're just going to answer with a reference to another question, it's better to do it by submitting a close-as-duplicate recommendation.

Comment: @Barmar How can I do that?